# How do i put a specific image to a random Imagebutton?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

So I'm working on an app in Android Studio(kotlin language)I have 3x3 Imagebuttons and a simple "start" button.How do I put a specific image(for example:number_1) in a random place in the 3x3 area when i hit the start button.

```
val images: MutableList<Int> = mutableListOf(
            number_1, number_2, number_3,
            number_4, number_5, number_6, number_7, number_8, number_9
        )
         
        val start: Button = findViewById(R.id.button)
        val button1: ImageButton = findViewById(R.id.imageButton)
        val button2: ImageButton = findViewById(R.id.imageButton2)
        val button3: ImageButton = findViewById(R.id.imageButton3)
        val button4: ImageButton = findViewById(R.id.imageButton4)
        val button5: ImageButton = findViewById(R.id.imageButton5)
        val button6: ImageButton = findViewById(R.id.imageButton6)
        val button7: ImageButton = findViewById(R.id.imageButton7)
        val button8: ImageButton = findViewById(R.id.imageButton8)
        val button9: ImageButton = findViewById(R.id.imageButton9)
        
        val buttons = arrayOf(
            button1, button2, button3, button4, button5,
            button6, button7, button8, button9)
```

Comment: `buttons.random()`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
val i = Random.nextInt(buttons.size)
buttons[i].setImageResource(number_1)
```

Or (as @m0skit0 wrote):

```
buttons.random().setImageResource(number_1)
```

And set listener:

```
start.setOnClickListener {
    // Code above
}
```

Comment: Also how do I know which Imagebutton I randomized, how to refer to it(for example if I want to click that randomized button)?                      var counter:Int=0 start.setOnClickListener{ counter++ if(counter==1){start.isClickable=false} buttons.random().setImageResource(number_1) buttons.random().setImageResource(number_2) buttons.random().setImageResource(number_3) }

Comment: @Benzo save it to a variable first. for example `var randomButton = buttons.random(); randomButton.setImageResource(number_1); randomButton.performClick()`

Comment: @Benzo, you will get a reference to an `ImageButton` with `val randomButton = buttons.random()`. Then you can set a click listener: `randomButton.setOnClickListener { ... }`. You also can set click listeners to every `ImageButton`.